# How can pip know a package's last version?

Tags: python, pip

I use pip to manage my packages, but how can I know a package's newest version?

I use the

```
pip install --upgrade eventlet
```

find the result the version did not change. still is `eventlet (0.21.0)`.

But in the [GitHub](https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet), you see the doc the newest version is `v0.22.1`.

Comment: what python version are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a package is not updated on pypi, you cannot pip install packagename to get the latest version. If you absolutely want the latest version you can install it directly from git

```
git clone <git URL of library>
```

cd into the directory and install the package:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: You can install directly from Git repositories with `pip`: `pip install git+https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet`.

Comment: you can try 
pip : pip install git+git://github.com/eventlet/eventlet

Comment: and whether there is a way to see the last version on pypi?

Comment: I'm sorry, there's not a way that I know of from the command line. Pycharm does have a way to see all your module versions and their latest versions though.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the list of all the modules that can be updated i.e. the modules with updated available you can use:

`pip list --outdated`

This will give you the output like

`....
ipython (6.2.1) - Latest: 6.3.1 [wheel]
....`

allowing you to chose the packages you want to update